Remove "Home" and "Shop" from WooCommerce Breadcrum
I have an issue with my woocommerce breadcrumb. Indeed, there is constantly "Home / Shop /" before the actual categories that I want.
I would like to have only the specific categories, subcategory then product, as these two are always repetitively here.
Eventually if the solution is easier, I could keep "shop" as the beginning of the breadcrumb.
Any clue on how to fix that?
breadcrum example
Unfortunately I cannot give access to this staging as it's under development
I checked all settings of woocommerce, but couldn't find something that refers to that
Also googled it, but the solutions seemed quite complex, to get an entirely custom breadcrumb, I'm wondering if there is simple solution here

Based on Remove "Shop" from Woocommerce breadcrumbs you can try the following to Remove "Home" and "Shop" from WooCommerce breadcrumb on single product pages:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'remove_home_and_shop_crumb', 20, 2 );
function remove_home_and_shop_crumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    // On single product pages
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // Loop through crumps
        foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
            // Remove "Home" and "Shop"
            if( in_array($crumb[0], [__('Home', 'Woocommerce'), 'Accueil']) 
            || in_array($crumb[0], [__('Shop', 'Woocommerce'), 'Boutique']) ) {
                unset($crumbs[$key]);
            }
        }
        return array_values($crumbs);
    }
    return $crumbs;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work for you.
